# NServiceBus - access queue on different machine

Tags: msmq, nservicebus

I have no experience in working with NServiceBus, and I'd like to make sure if my scenario can be achieved. I have two machines: A and B. On machine A there was deployed a component that send messages via nservicebus to the queue which exists on the same machine. I have another component that should receive the messages. Unfortunately, I cannot deploy it now on machine A (it works on machine B), but I'd like to fetch the messages that were already put by the sender. Is it possible? When I try to define input queue in the receiver like this:

```
    <MsmqTransportConfig InputQueue="RetrieverClient2@MachineA" ErrorQueue="RetrieverClient2_errors@MachineA" NumberOfWorkerThreads="1" MaxRetries="5"/>
```

I get exception:  Input queue must be on the same machine as this process. Is there any method of configuration that I can use to retrieve messages from this remote queue provided I know it exists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're changing the deployment topology of your system, you should configure the first component to send its messages to the second machine and then just do a one-off manual move of the messages left to the second queue.

Answer (score 1):

For a queue on "localhost" you should not include the "@localhost". Your config would look like this:

```
<MsmqTransportConfig InputQueue="RetrieverClient2" ErrorQueue="RetrieverClient2_errors" NumberOfWorkerThreads="1" MaxRetries="5"/>
```

The @ symobl makes the endpoint think you're referring to a remote queue. You can't use a remote queue for an endpoint's input queue because the performance of trying to do a remote transactional receive on MSMQ is quite poor. (See "What about MSMQ v4" section of [Load Balancing with the Distributor](http://support.nservicebus.com/customer/portal/articles/859556-load-balancing-with-the-distributor))

Udi's answer is quite correct if changing the deployment topology is what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: I edited the question. I made mistake in the queue name - it should be Machine2, not localhost. But your answer is still correct. I can't use remote queue in this case.